# Get text and location from Json in android

Tags: android, json, textview

I have this bit of code that show me the text from the json file, but I would like to check the text if there's a specific word in it.

Here's my code :

```
    if (currentLocation.distanceTo(myModel.getNearest()) < 500) {

        if (said != true) {

            String seriousWarning = (myModel.getNearest().getProvider());
            tts.speak(seriousWarning, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            said = true;


        }
```

the     myModel.getNearest()) is here :

```
  public Location getNearest(){
    nearest = cameras.get(0);
    return nearest;
}
```

and JSON file :

```
 {
"lng":0.18077 ,
"lat": 43.00854 ,
"name":"Orange Store",
"tribe":"1",
"id":"1",
"verified":"1"
},
```

I've tried this but didn't work :

```
if (currentLocation.distanceTo(myModel.getNearest()) < 500) {

    if (said != true) {

        String seriousWarning = (myModel.getNearest().getProvider());
        tts.speak(seriousWarning, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        said = true;
 if  (seriousWarning.equals("Orange")) 
              sign.setText("JAckbot");

    }
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's no json related code. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what is your question? and could you share the JSON file?

Comment: I would like to do something like this :  if (seriousWarning.equals("highway")) {
sign.setText("");

Comment: use seriousWarning.contains("highway")

Answer (score 0):

Simply store text in any String variable like:

```
 String s1 = [your text];
 if(s1.contains([specific word]))
{
do something if text contains specific word
}else
{
do something is text do not contain word
}
```

Comment: can you please tell how you did it? and problem you faced

Comment: your are setting seriousWarning = "You are close to the store " + (myModel.getNearest().getProvider()); and then checking seriousWarning.equals("Orange") this will always be false

Comment: you have to use seriousWarning.contains() not seriousWarning.equals()

Comment: when i run the app the word "Orange" is in the (myModel.getNearest().getProvider())...
i just tried the contains and didn't work

Comment: yeah but you are adding "You are close to the store " to orange....` + (myModel.getNearest().getProvider())`

Comment: even when I put only the (myModel.getNearest().getProvider()), it don't detect the word..

Comment: I guess you should take programming lessons first.. don't put such thing here.. you don't know what you are doing.